Understanding 区分特性ごとに区分する
While reading the definition for 交差分類, I am uncertain with this sentence:

区分特性ごとに区分し，区分特性適用の優先順位を定めておけば，交差分類は生じない.

It seems like 区分特性ごとに区分する has two possible interpretations:

To classify by characteristic.

To classify for each characteristic.


Judging from the context, it seems like 2 is the most likely interpretation. Plus, 区分特性 is something shared by all objects in a group, so 1 does not make sense.
To illustrate what 区分特性ごとに区分する means, suppose we need to find a way to classify fruits. The common traits shared by all fruits are color and sourness. We first classify fruits by color, then classify by sourness.
Is that right?

I think it would have been easier to understand, and also categorize things, if they changed the order and put 区分特性適用の優先順位を定めておき，区分特性ごとに区分すれば...

@aguijonazo I doubt it. In this algorithm, 区分特性ごとに区分する can be done without determining the 優先順位 beforehand. AKIRA is a Japanese animated action film, and Matrix is an American live-action sci-fi film. You don't need any 優先順位 yet in this step.

@naruto - Whatever, and we don't have to agree.

This 区分特性ごとに区分する means to give (tentative) classifications (to all members) for each characteristic.
But it's not like this:

classify fruits by color, then classify by sourness

Instead, it's like this:


First, classify all berries by both color and sourness:

Berry A: red and sour
Berry B: blue and sour
Berry C: red and sweet
Berry D: blue and sweet


Then determine the final classification according to the precedence of applying characteristics (区分特性適用の優先順位)


In this example, if blueness takes precedence over sourness, the final classification can be determined in one way:

A: sourberry
B: blueberry
C: sweetberry
D: blueberry

If sourness takes precedence over blueness:

A: sourberry
B: sourberry
C: redberry
D: blueberry

The same principle can be used to consistently categorize animals, music, tumors and so on. Essentially, the mental model here is a flowchart like this (although the algorithm suggested in your link is less efficient).

Thanks. The seemingly simple concept of classification is more complicated than I thought. I interpreted 区分特性適用の優先順位 differently. Using your example, suppose sourness takes precedence over color. A, B, C and D will be "sour and red", "sour and blue", "sweet and red" and "sweet and blue" respectively. Notice that the sourness modifier comes first before the color modifier. I classify by sourness first before by color. I think the suggested algorithm is similar to 階層構造 construction discussed in section 2.3 from this paper.

@JohnDavies No, the algorithm suggested by your link is not about defining multilayer (or multidimensional, or fine-grained) classifications like "sourblueberry" or "redsweetberry". It's about defining the most important characteristic and ignoring less important ones.

I see. Also, maybe it is more clear if you instead translate 区分特性ごとに区分する as "for each characteristic, give classifications to all members." Which characteristic to start from depends on 区分特性適用の優先順位. That "and" part is bit confusing to me.

@JohnDavies I re-read your paper, and I'm sorry, I made a wrong comment. The 階層構造 described in Fig 1 indicates that genre (action, fantasy) takes higher precedence over country, and it can avoid unfortunate 交差分類. Adopting that 階層構造 as a rule, we can say AKIRA is an action film rather than an anime film or a Japanese film. Fig 2 (multidimensional classification) is another way of avoiding 交差分類, but it's not mentioned in the original text in question.
